# How to enable Svelte Google Chrome Dev extension

Tags: laravel, svelte, inertiajs

I have just managed to install Svelte on top of Inertia js into a Laravel environment. So far it appears to work. However, I can not get the Svelte extension in google Chrome to work. I have read some comments that somewhere you need to have "dev:true" set where the default is "dev:false" I have also run npm run dev to no affect.

Any one know how to make this work?

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `dev: true` props didn't add to Rollup or Webpack config file. Below is a link from the official docs:

[Enable Svelte Google Chrome Dev Extension](https://github.com/RedHatter/svelte-devtools#enabling-dev-mode)